# How to remove ghost layer in Qgis?

Tags: qgis, layers

I added a delimited text layer to a Qgis 2.0 project, working in Windows, but it got added wrong: It didn't appear in the list of layers on the left panel, nor did it show in the map canvas. However, when I try to use Points2One to create a polygon, it appears in the list of available layers, but if I select it Points2One generates an empty layer.

(If I add it again it works fine, but I can only eliminate the second, working layer, not the first one, and I can't delete it from the layer list because it doesn't show there.)

Any idea of what might be the cause?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this behavior reproducible? Also on other machines? Does it happen with the latest QGIS version? If yes, you should file a bug report.

Comment: It's not the first time it happens, but I can't find what are the circumstances that cause it. However, most times the bad layer appears in the layer list and I can remove it. I haven't used Qgis in any other computer, and I didn't find it in the previous version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The QGIS project file can be edited with any text editor. So you can look into it, and remove the layer entry that does not show up in the table of content.

The file has a XML structure, so be sure to catch the closing tag as well.

To be safe, make a copy of the project file before editing.